# Questions about Java constructor, for class and its super class

Tags: java, class, parameters, constructor, super

I'm trying to figure out how the constructors work in the following program. Basically there is a `Seeker` class that extends `Player` class, and a `Game` class that contains `Seeker` object, as shown in the code below.

My question is, when the `Game` class instantiates `mySeeker` using `mySeeker = new Seeker( "Sally", this );`  does `this` invoke the player's constructor? If so, where did it pass on the name of the game?  I saw a `Game g` in the constructor for `Player`, but I can't figure out how the game `myGame` (in the `main` method) has been passed to the `Seeker`.

//Game class

```
class Game {

   Seeker mySeeker;
   int gridSize;

   Game( int gs ) {
     gridSize = gs;
     mySeeker = new Seeker( "Sally", this ); //what does 'this' do here? why it does not include the name of the game?
   }

   void play() {
     mySeeker.seek();
   }
}
```

//Player class

```
  abstract class Player { 

     private Point location;
     private String name;
     Game game;

Player( Point p, String n, Game g ) {
    location = p; 
    name = n;
    game = g;
}
```

//Seeker class

```
class Seeker extends Player {

   Seeker( String n, Game g ) {
       super( new Point( 0, 0 ), n, g ); // seeker starts at 0,0
}
```

//Main Program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int gridSize = 3; // default value
    Game myGame = new Game( gridSize );
    myGame.play();
}
```

Comment: `this` is simply a reference to the current object. So when you call `new Seeker( "Sally", this );`, you're passing the current `Game` object as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, when the `Game` class instantiate `mySeeker using`mySeeker = new Seeker( "Sally", this );``` does ``this ``` invoke the player's constructor?

No.

The `Player` constructor >>is<< being invoked, but not because of `this`.  In the context where that statements comes from, `this` will denote a `Game` instance.  It is "just a parameter" that is being passed to the `Seeker` constructor.

The `Player constructor is being invoked in the`Seeker` constructor; specifically this line:

```
    super( new Point( 0, 0 ), n, g );
```

What happens is that when you `new` the `Seeker`, the `Seeker` constructor is called, and it immediately calls the `Player` constructor, via the `super` call.

---

> If so, where did it pass on the name of the game?

The line above is where the `Game` object is being passed to `Player`.  See the `g` parameter?  It the same `Game` object that you passed as `this`.

(The code you have shown us doesn't support a "name" for the game.  What is being passed is a reference.  And when you assign the new `Game` instance to `myGame`, it isn't the "name of the game".  The `myGame` variable is simply that ... a variable ... that can contain a reference to *some* `Game` object.)

Answer (score 0):

The "this" reference is referring to the instance of the Game class. The game class is lending itself to the seeker/player class so the seeker/player class can access data from the game class.

edit:
The "seeking" is being handed "this" instance of "Game" and using the "super" command to pass data to it's inherited "player"

Answer (score 0):

`Seeker` gets instantiated with a name and a `Game` object. Passing `this` is just a reference to the current object. The `Seeker` will be created with the already created `Game` object meaning the `Seeker` can access data from the `Game` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
mySeeker = new Seeker( "Sally", this )
```

The above code allocate a Seeker object, and then execute its constructor to initiate its value, and then assign the variable **mySeeker** with a reference on the new Seeker object.

The constructor is called with two arguments: a string and **this**. **this** refers to the current object that is executing the above code, in this case it refers to the Game object that is being constructed.